# why does mysql workbench allow just one self-contained file to be imported into db in?

Tags: mysql-workbench

I wonder why MySQL workbench allows just `one self-contained file` to be imported into a DB? Whereas when you `export` MySQL DB in workbench, you can export everything in just one step.
I think this is quite unreasonable and there's got to be a way to import multiple files at once.

[image]

As you can see, there is no way to import multiple SQL scripts.
does that mean that if I have 100 SQL scripts to import, I have to do this 100 times?
Your Help would be very appreciated:)!!
MY LOCAL MACHINE:  windows 10

Comment: What about the "Load Folder Contents" button isn't it what you are looking for? Checking the option right above this one?

Comment: You really could have checked the documentation... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import-management.html

Comment: I've already tried that. @JorgeCampos with no luck... When I tried that, it said import completed but nothing's imported into db... import only worked when I imported one self-contained file..

Comment: @Shadow thank you for the info. but the way docs suggests `import from dump project folder` didn't worked for me...